# google sheet vlookup function analysis error

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet:

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| exercise | date | bicep |  | exercise | bicep |
| push | 25-08-2023 |  |  | push | 2 |

in C2 I put the following formula: =VLOOKUP(A2,E2:F2,2,false) expecting seeing the value 2, but I get a generic error of Analysis error of the formula (the language is set to Italian, I've translated the message for you, so it can differ from the english one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try either syntaxes and see what happens:*

```js
=VLOOKUP(A2;E:F;2;)
```

---

```js
 =VLOOKUP(A2,E:F,2,)
```

Comment: I'm speechless, the semicolon worked for me. Can't belive there's such a thing... Very disappointed. Thanks!

Comment: [this article](https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/sheets-location/) on syntax differences based on sheets country location setting should be helpful

Answer (score 0):

false VLOOKUP(A2,E2:F2,2,false)

remove row number from E2 and F2

VLOOKUP(A2,E:F,2,false)